# Loop, array, mysql, Bash, Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, for-loop

I want to write a script that sends the select to the database

```
data_path="https://localhost/public/"
data_name=(PXL_20220628_152928222.mp4 PXL_20220628_163301667.mp4)
for q in "${data_name[@]}";
do
data_l=$(sudo mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u ck****** -p"*******" -e "SELECT iddata FROM 
ck*****.data WHERE links = '$data_path$q'")
done
echo "$data_l"
```

In response I get only one record (id first file PXL_20220628_152928222.mp4 )

The loop is not working

Comment: It's working fine, you're overwriting. Answer in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your script to a file with a shebang, added an `echo` in front of the `sudo` to show the command being executed and moved the one AFTER the loop *inside* to show the result.

```
#! /bin/bash
data_path="https://localhost/public/"
data_name=(PXL_20220628_152928222.mp4 PXL_20220628_163301667.mp4)
for q in "${data_name[@]}"; do
    # data_l=$(sudo mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u ck****** -p"*******" -e " SELECT iddata FROM ck*****.data WHERE links = '$data_path$q'
    data_l=$(echo "$q")
    echo "$data_l" # this was outside the loop
done
# echo "$data_l" # not here, this only reports the LAST value
```

Running it:

```
PXL_20220628_152928222.mp4
PXL_20220628_163301667.mp4
```

You were assigning it, but not reporting it, then overwriting with the second assignment, and only reporting that one after the loop was done.

Just move the echo at the end inside the loop.

Comment: You're right 
I checked, echo before loop works.
Thanks!
_____________________________________

If replace array
data_name=(PXL_20220628_152928222.mp4 PXL_20220628_163301667.mp4)
to 
data_name=$(ls *mp4)

No loop result

Comment: ls to an array 
data_name=($(ls *mp4))
did not help

Comment: data_name=($(ls *mp4))
for q in "${data_name[@]}";
everything works

Comment: [Do NOT](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) use `data_name=($(ls *mp4))` - just use `data_name=(*mp4)`.